# "sub domain" in lnternal network

Tags: domain-controller, subdomain, hosts

i have a small network under a Windows domain-controller. the server (Win2012) run a WebSite which is accessible by typing the machine-name (`srv/`).
i want add a website with binding to `sub-domain`: `workers.srv/`.

Where (dns service, hosts, router), and how I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy solution is to create a dns record on your network dns server. Create a type A record with the name you want pointing your server ip. Just make sure every computer in your network use that dns server.

Comment: the windows dns server looks very complicated. I have never done this action, you can direct me where to add what?

Comment: Just go to the dns management console _To open DNS, click Start, click Control Panel, double-click Administrative Tools, and then double-click DNS. _ after right click on your domain name and create a new type A  record, on the name put the name you want without the domain and the ip address, OK and it's done!!

Comment: thank! it work. but i need type full path: `workers.srv.local` instead `worker.srv`, like for the exist website which is also accessible by tapping a `srv` only. you have an idea what I can do? thanks again...

Comment: [Read This](http://serverfault.com/questions/18665/subdomain-dns-on-windows-server-2003-needing-fully-qualified-name), i never do this so i can't help you sory!